# contact form validation problem (Validation is bypassed on send button)

Tags: javascript, validation, email, forms, live

I am using livevalidation script on my contact form.But i dont know what is the problem whenever i click submitt or send button.
It just only checks the dropdown selection and other fields go empty and form is validated. I checked every example on livevalidation site but no help. Mine is not working....
It dont check the presense function in all my fields........I dont know what to do

You can check my contact page online here.[link text](http://www.coffeedesign.net/contact.html)

If you need code then i am pasting it here toooooo........

Code for form is here

```
 <div class="subFillC">
        <form id="form1" action="contactengine.php" method="post" name="form1">
          <p><label for="name">Name</label> <input type="text" name="name" id="Name" size=
          "30" /> </p>

          <p><label for="email">Email</label> <input type="text" name="email" id="Email" size=
          "30" /></p>

          <p><label for="web">Select Option</label> <select name="service" id="service">
            <option value="None" selected="selected">
              None
            </option>

            <option value="Website Design">
              Website Design
            </option>

            <option value="Website Redesign">
              Website Redesign
            </option>

            <option value="Logo/Corporate Design">
              Logo Design/Corporate Design
            </option>

            <option value="Other">
              Other
            </option>
          </select></p>

          <p><label for="email">What is <img src="images/cap.jpg" width="50" height=
          "15" /></label> <input type="text" name="cap" id="cap" size="30" /></p>

          <p><label for="message">Message</label>
          <textarea id="Messagefield" name="message" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```

Send

And in the end i have script just after the form tag
which is below

new LiveValidation('Name', { wait: 500 }).add(Validate.Presence);new LiveValidation('Email', { wait: 500 }).add(Validate.Email);
new LiveValidation('Messagefield', { wait: 500 }).add(Validate.Presence);var service = new LiveValidation('service' , {onlyOnSubmit: true });service.add( Validate.Exclusion, { within: [ 'None' ] } );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not correctly calling validation for all the fields. You must make an instance of LiveValidation object before calling the add function.

For each field (Name, Email, MessageField) replace:

```
new LiveValidation('Name', { wait: 500 }).add(Validate.Presence);
```

With:

```
var LV_Name = new LiveValidation('Name', { wait: 500 });
LV_Name.add(Validate.Presence);
```

Here is complete JS snippet with LiveValidation placed inside document.ready jQuery function that will execute when DOM is ready:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="contact_files/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="contact_files/livevalidation_standalone.js"></script><!-- Let's do the animation -->
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$(function() {

    var LV_Name = new LiveValidation('name',{ wait: 500 });
    LV_Name.add(Validate.Presence);

    var LV_Email = new LiveValidation('email', {onlyOnSubmit: true });
    LV_Email.add(Validate.Presence);

    var LV_Message= new LiveValidation('message', { wait: 500 });
    LV_Message.add(Validate.Presence);

    var service = new LiveValidation('service' , {onlyOnSubmit: true });
    service.add( Validate.Exclusion, { within: [ 'None' ] } );

    // set opacity to nill on page load
    $("ul#menu span").css("opacity","0");
    // on mouse over
    $("ul#menu span").hover(function () {
        // animate opacity to full
        $(this).stop().animate({
            opacity: 1
            }, 'slow');
        },
        // on mouse out
        function () {
            // animate opacity to nill
            $(this).stop().animate({
                opacity: 0
                }, 'slow');
            });
    });
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: Okay now i have changed all the code according to your answer, but still the same problem, it only displays the message for the options field, it doesn't check the other fields presence.
<b>when you click submit button after selecting any option other than none from dropdown.It submitts the form....

Comment: It is working when you place your code to execute when DOM is ready, I tried to place this code inside the $(function() {}) at the bottom and it is working.

Comment: can you give me the code you placed, beacause on my side empty values are going to the php page and presence is not checked at all. i am a beginner in java so plz guid me with writing simple code here

Comment: Yes now its working, Great and superb help for me........
I really needed that from a long time.

Comment: although there is one problem now, my contact form validation is working but now the hover animation of my menu items is not working, what should i do now.......is there any problem in this function code